# Vaadin Grid always selects last row

Tags: select, grid, vaadin

I need help debugging the follow issue:
When I click on a Vaadin Grid with 3 rows, it ignores the click on any but the last row and always selects the 3rd row.

Code is as follows:

```
    // declare Grid objects
public final Grid<SoapKPIContainer> soapKPIOverviewGridDisplay;

..
public SoapKPIOverviewView(SoapKPIRepository soapKPIRepository, Navigator navigator,
                           BpspSoapCheckCommunications bpspSoapCheckCommunications,
                           UIMessageByLocaleService messageByLocaleService) {
    ..

    this.soapKPIOverviewGridDisplay = new Grid<>(SoapKPIContainer.class);
    this.soapKPIOverviewGridDisplay.setColumns();

    Grid.Column<SoapKPIContainer, ?> lastAlarmStatusIconColumn = this.soapKPIOverviewGridDisplay.addColumn("lastAlarmStatusIcon", new ImageRenderer<>());
    lastAlarmStatusIconColumn.setSortable(false);
    lastAlarmStatusIconColumn.setResizable(false);
    lastAlarmStatusIconColumn.setWidth(80.0f);
    lastAlarmStatusIconColumn.setCaption(messageByLocaleService.getMessage("label.lastalarmstatus"));

    Grid.Column<SoapKPIContainer, ?> activationIconColumn = this.soapKPIOverviewGridDisplay.addColumn("activationIcon", new ImageRenderer<>());
    activationIconColumn.setSortable(false);
    activationIconColumn.setResizable(false);

    this.soapKPIOverviewGridDisplay.getDefaultHeaderRow().getCell("lastAlarmStatusIcon").setHtml(messageByLocaleService.getMessage("label.lastalarmstatus"));
    this.soapKPIOverviewGridDisplay.getDefaultHeaderRow().getCell("activationIcon").setHtml(messageByLocaleService.getMessage("label.activationicon"));

    this.soapKPIOverviewGridDisplay.addColumn(SoapKPIContainer::getKpiName).
    setCaption(messageByLocaleService.getMessage("header.kpiName"));

    ..

    this.setSizeFull();
    this.soapKPIOverviewGridDisplay.setSizeFull();       
    this.soapKPIOverviewGridDisplay.setHeight(400, Unit.PIXELS);

    this.soapKPIService = new SoapKPIService(soapKPIRepository);

    this.soapKPIOverviewGridDisplay.setItems( soapKPIService.toContainer( soapKPIService.findAllSoapKPI() ) );

    ..  
    // adding Listener for the Grid to enable for the user to select single KPIs
    soapKPIOverviewGridDisplay.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    soapKPIOverviewGridDisplay.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener(e -> {
        log.debug("asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener " + e.getValue());           
        if ( e.getValue() != null) {

            log.debug("asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener findSoapKPIById #" + e.getValue().getKpiId());   

            testKPIDefView.setEnabled(true);
            soapKPI = soapKPIService.findSoapKPIById( e.getValue().getKpiId() );

            changeEnabled.setVisible(true);

            if( soapKPI.getEnabled() == 1)
                changeEnabled.setCaption(messageByLocaleService.getMessage("button.disable"));

            else
                changeEnabled.setCaption(messageByLocaleService.getMessage("button.enable"));

        }

        else {

            testKPIDefView.setEnabled(false);
            changeEnabled.setVisible(false);
            soapKPI = null;
        }
    });
    ..
    soapKPIOverviewLayout.addComponent(soapKPIOverviewGridDisplay);
```

[image: Image with selection in 2nd row]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what line in the code cause it to break, but I found that overriding the equals method of the row object makes the problem go away:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {

    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof SoapKPIContainer)) {
        return false;
    }

    SoapKPIContainer container = (SoapKPIContainer) o;

    return this.getKpiId() == container.getKpiId();
}
```

Comment: It was my first thought that it might be a problem with `equals` of your Grid's item class. When overriding `equals` then make sure that you implement `hashCode()` as well, so your objects can be used in `HashSet` etc. Another option is to supply a custom DataProvider to the grid that implements the [getId](https://vaadin.com/api/8.3.2/com/vaadin/data/provider/DataProvider.html#getId-T-) method with e.g. your `kpiId`.